# How to speed up merging multiple PDF files using PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to merge 5 pdf files using pypdf2 using this code:

```py
import os

from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger

source_dir = r"C:\Users\Aparns\Downloads\speeddata"
merger = PdfMerger(strict=True)

for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if item.endswith("pdf"):
        merger.append(source_dir + item)

merger.write(source_dir + r"C:\Users\Aparns\Downloads\speeddata\Complete.pdf")
merger.close()
```

The pdf files are stored in the speeddata directory. This process is taking too much time for responding. Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: You had a bug in your code originally: `PdfMerger((strict=True))`. I fixed it as this was not what the question was about.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the current maintainer of pypdf and `PyPDF2`. I don't think there is a faster way to do it with `pypdf` / `PyPDF2` (or any other pypdf project). If there is, please let me know and we can add it to [the merging documentation](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/merging-pdfs.html).

A few recommendations:

1. Switch to `pypdf`. `PyPDF2` is deprecated.
2. Use `strict=False` (the default)
3. Avoid `open`ing the files yourself. pypdf does that - and it also closes the file handles again

Answer (score -2):

Merge two PDF files using Python
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger. #Create and instance of PdfFileMerger() class.
merger = PdfFileMerger() #Create a list with file names.
pdf_files = ['pdf_files/sample_page1.pdf', 'pdf_files/sample_page2.pdf'] #Iterate over the list of file names.
merger. append(pdf_file)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).